# onEndReached in Flatlist issue

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

If I enclose the flatlist in a View then my onEndReached triggers infinitely if I remove the enclosing View onEndReached is not triggered at all.

```
 render() {
    return (
        <Root>
            <Container>
                <Content>
                    <View>
                        {this.state.listView && (
                            <FlatList
                                data={this.state.variants}
                                keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
                                onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
                                onEndReached={({ distanceFromEnd }) => {
                                    console.log(
                                        "on end reached ",
                                        distanceFromEnd
                                    );
                                    this.loadMore();
                                }}
                                numColumns={1}
                                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                                    <CatalogRow
                                        item={item}
                                        in_wishlist={this.state.in_wishlist}
                                        toggleWishlist={() =>
                                            this.toggleWishlist(item.title)
                                        }
                                        listView={this.state.listView}
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
                        )}
                    </View>
                </Content>
            </Container>
        </Root>
    );
}
```

And my `distanceFromEnd` takes values like 0 , 960,1200 when it is trigerred. What does it indicate?
I'm using  react-native 0.47.2

Comment: I don't think there is anything really wrong in your code. Just try updating your react-native version to latest and check. There could be a bug in their implementation which would be fixed in latest versions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was because of the enclosing `<Content>` tag. Sometimes embedding react-native tags with native-base tags causes such issues. I replaced the content and container tag with `View` tags and now it works fine.

Answer (score 15):

I have same problem with react-native 0.50.3

`<Flatlist>` must not be used in a `<ScrollView>` if you want to use `onEndReached` because Flatlist can not found the height.

Use a `<View>` instead

Comment: I have an article screen, i want to load comments when user reaches the end of article body. How i can deal with this problem? Right now i have flatlist inside scrollview which keeps triggering onEndReached indefinitely.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55748813/flatlist-inside-scrollview-onendreached

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem with RN 0.52

That look like because Flatlist can not found the heigh. So he can not find the end of list.

Fix by wrap your flatlist by a View with flex=1

```
<View style={{flex: 1}} > <Flatlist /> <View>
```

Comment: Helpful... valid answer!!

Answer (score 1):

I would use it like this:

```
handleMore = () => {
    // fetch more here
};

<FlatList
    onEndReached={this.handleMore}
/>
```