# Flatlist inside Scrollview onEndReached

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a Flatlist inside animated ScrollView. Flatlist has onEndReached implemented with threshold set to 0.5. The problem I am facing is onEndReached keeps triggering without even scrolling.

I have an article view with a body. I want to load the comments when user reaches the end of article body, and onEndReached should only trigger when comments end is reached.

Please suggest if I should deal with the problem differently, I am stuck on this for quite a while.

Comment: debounce the api call

Comment: I am already debouncing onEndReached

Comment: there must be something wrong with your debounce if it still is getting called without scrolling

Comment: any luck with this issue ??

Comment: I guess it is not recommended to use multiple scrollviews like this. Using a single flatlist with header could be the solution.

Comment: As @gamingumar said, use your FlatList comment and put as a ListHeaderComponent your article body.

Comment: @kentuckyss putting large view on ListHeaderComponent isn't a wise choice. since Header would be reloaded on pull to refresh

Comment: @TomSawyer can you recommend a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot do without the ScrollView, I fixed this by setting a fixed height for FlatList in style, and set `nestedScrollEnabled` to true for both ScrollView and FlatList.